# Rails 7 - consuming multiple API response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

In my Rails 7 app I've got an integration with 3rd party API. The response might include `response['next_page']` which means that the response is paginated. I want to consume all the pages when the `next_page` key is present in the response. Below my client:

```
module Customers
  module Settlements
    class Client
      def self.with_account(account) = new(account.id)

      def initialize(account_id)
        @conn = setup_conn(Rails.application.config.settlements_url, account_id)
      end

      def fetch_report(page:, limit: 500)
        handle_response(@conn.get("reports?page=#{page}&limit=#{limit}"))
      end
     
     # (...) other private methods
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any common way to consume all pages?

Comment: Write a recursive method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `while` there is next page, or `loop` and break, or:

```rb
def get page:
  mock_api = {
    1 => {next_page: 2, data: "stuff1"},
    2 => {next_page: 3, data: "stuff2"},
    3 => {data: "stuffLast"}
  }
  mock_api[page]
end

def fetch_all page: 1, &b
   return unless page                         # finish when no more pages

   response = get(page:)                      # get things
   yield response[:data]                      # process things
   fetch_all page: response[:next_page], &b   # get more things
end
```

```rb
>> fetch_all { |data| p data }
"stuff1"
"stuff2"
"stuffLast"
=> nil
```